# VBA powerpoint Make textBox border invisible

Tags: vba, powerpoint

New to vba. I am Trying to Make a vba textbox border invisible but the BorderStyle function is not doing anything. Attached below is a picture of the box.

Here is the code, it's very straightforward:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

TextBox1.MultiLine = True

TextBox1.Font.Size = 9

TextBox1.BorderStyle = 0

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You can set the border style manually. Do you need VBA for this?

Comment: Have you tried recording  a macro which does the border thing then looking at the code?

Comment: @Programnik - unfortunately Powerpoint does not have the option to record a macro.

Comment: In PP 2010 I see Macro button on View tab

Comment: @Programnik - but that is not the same as the "Record Macro" button.

Comment: Stupid power point.

Comment: @BigBen VBA is required as I need to able to write while the presentation is in presentation mode. It's an interactive presentation

Comment: Right - but you can set the border style from within the VBA editor manually. Or am I missing something? https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnLGU.png

Comment: @BigBen This is what I'm trying to figure out. I thought the function TextBox1.BorderStyle = 0 would remove the border but isn't working. Just to clarify here I'm not talking about the purple border it's the small grey border around the textbox.

Comment: Yeah. Try toggling the border style manually in the VB Editor - to `1 - fmBorderStyleSingle`, and then back to `0 - fmBorderStyleNone`. Works for me.

Comment: Have you a demo of the code? Sorry very new to all this and appreciate the help.

Comment: Should I have: TextBox1.fmBorderStyleSingle = 1?

Comment: Do it manually. Check the screenshot I provided. https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnLGU.png There's a dropdown on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close this question out:

No need to do this with VBA. You can change the border style manually in the VBA Editor.

Toggle the *BorderStyle* to `1 - fmBorderStyleSingle` and then back to `0 - fmBorderStyleNone`.

[image]